# How to use a DbSet<T> with a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, interface, generic-programming, dbset

I have an interface:

```
public interface ILanguageEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }

    string Code { get; set; }

    string Culture { get; set; }

    string LocalName { get; set; }

    bool IsRightToLeft { get; set; }
}
```

And I've implemented that as a Entity like this:

```
public class LanguageEntity : ILanguageEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Culture { get; set; }

    public string LocalName { get; set; }

    public bool IsRightToLeft { get; set; }
}
```

In my service I want to have a property for this entity which returns its DbSet like this:

```
public class LanguageService : ILanguageService
{
    public ApplicationContext Context { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ILanguageEntity> DbSet { get { return Context.Set<LanguageEntity>(); } }

}
```

But it's not possible because I'm returning a `DbSet<LanguageEntity>` type while I must return a `DbSet<ILanguageEntity>` type as compiler says. What should I do?

Comment: Just curious, Why you need to have more interface for your model LanguageEntity?

Comment: Because I'm trying to make my project modular and I need to access the LanguageEntity from the other modules, and other modules doesn't know where the LanguageEntity is. However they know how to use LanguageService.

Answer (score 0):

well i assume that `ApplicationContext` should have atleast one `ILanguageEntity` `DbSet`

Here is what i came up with :

```
public class LanguageService : ILanguageService
{
    public ApplicationContext Context { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ILanguageEntity> DbSet
    {
        get
        {
            return Context.LanguageEntities;
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ILanguageEntity> LanguageEntities { get; set; }
}

public interface ILanguageService
{
    DbSet<ILanguageEntity> DbSet { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If I use an interface instead of class for DbSet, the migration will returns and error while it tries to update the database. this is the error:

The type 'RPSP.Framework.IEntities.Language.ILanguageEntity' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.